# Override an overridden method (C#)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to override an overridden method (if that makes sense!) in C#.

I have a scenario similar to the below, but when I have a breakpoint in the SampleMethod() in the "C" class it's not being hit, whilst the same breakpoint in the "B" method is being hit.

```
public class A
{
      protected virtual void SampleMethod() {}
}

public class B : A 
{
      protected override void SampleMethod()
      {
           base.SampleMethod(); 
      }
}

public class C : B
{
      protected override void SampleMethod() 
      {
           base.SampleMethod(); 
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:**

Ok, the context would help:

This is in the context of a composite control so class A inherits from CompositeControl and calls SampleMethod() after overriding the CreateChildControls() method.

Comment: Come into the same situation,after check the the `calling code`,problem solved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without seeing the code that calls SampleMethod, my guess would be that you have an object of type B and call SampleMethod on that.

Comment: Yeah this was just a stupid mistake on my behalf - thanks for your (and everybody else who contributed) time spent on this though.

Answer (score 52):

Overriding can be performed in a chain as long as you like. The code you have shown is correct.

The only possible explanation for the behaviour you are seeing is that the object to which you are referring is actually of type `B`. I suggest that you double check this, and if things still don't make sense, post the other appropiate code.

Answer (score 4):

The breakpoint is more than likely not being hit because you actually instantiated an instance of the "B" class.

Method override resolution works based on the actual *runtime* type of the class whose method should be called. So, if you had the following code:

```
C c = new C();
c.SampleMethod();
```

and the following:

```
C c = new C();
B b = (B)c;
b.SampleMethod();
```

both the *runtime* types of the class whose `SampleMethod` will be called is type `B`.

Answer (score 2):

That solution works fine; although to actually use it outside the class the method is in, you need to set the access of `SampleMethod` to `public` rather than `protected` in all of the cases it appears, so:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void SampleMethod() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("lol");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void SampleMethod()
    {
        base.SampleMethod();
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void SampleMethod()
    {
        base.SampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on where SampleMethod is being accessed from. Virtual/Override methods do not have to be public.

Answer (score 2):

for Overriding more than once in the hierarchy use something like this

```
// abstract class
abstract class A
    {
        public abstract void MethodOne();
    }

// class B inherits A
class B : A
{
    public override void MethodOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From Class B");
    }
}

// class C inherits B
class C : B
{
    public override void MethodOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From Class C");
    }
}

// class D inherits C
class D : C
{
    public override void MethodOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From Class D");
    }
}

// etc......

// class Main method Class

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B[] TestArray = new B[3];
        B b1 = new B();
        C c1 = new C();
        D d1 = new D();

        TestArray[0] = b1;
        TestArray[1] = c1;
        TestArray[2] = d1;

        for (int i = 0; i < TestArray.Length; i++)
        {
            TestArray[i].MethodOne();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I did it in this code in this link
http://www.4shared.com/rar/0SG0Rklxce/OverridingMoeThanOnce.html

Answer (score -3):

Method overriding  is OOP feature that allows a child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its  parent classes.