# Chaining class inheritance with overriding methods

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

As part of a big framework (so i cant post a MCVE unfortunately) i am trying to [inherit a couple of times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1152925/7926064) to hide necessary initialization from the user of the class so the structure is

```
// internal base class
public class InternalBase
{
  // declared internal to avoid subclassing by user - visibility 
  // is handled in AssemblyInfo.cs so library can subclass
  internal InternalBase()
  {
  }

  public virtual void startup()
  {
    // perform necessary initialization
  }
}

// public base class the users should inherit from
public class PublicBase : InternalBase
{
  public override void startup()
  {
    // call base class to perform required init
    base.startup();

    // perform extra steps like check if init was performed correctly
  }
}

// user class trying to use the provided functionaly
public class Test : PublicBase
{
  public override void startup()
  {
    // this is put here by convention/template to ensure execution of
    // required init - if this could be avoided, even better
    base.startup();

    // users are allowed to put their own init here
    // perform user init code
  }
}
```

Now as soon as i want to step into `base.startup()` in the `Test` class, the system behaves strange. Breakpoints in the other methods are not hit. An exception is thrown from somewhere completely different, log output suggests that the program continued a bit. When the exception (type is from the framework) is thrown, there is no callstack.

Should this work in principle, how could i provide such functionality or debug what i have?

Comment: Read [ask] and _do_ create a [mcve]. This code does not reproduce the issue you mention. There's probably multiple projects, perhaps even outside the solution, and some assemblies are not matching your source files causing breakpoints not to be hit.

Comment: What do you mean by "behaves strange"? Please add the excetpion you get. Is there anyother thread that produces the error?

Comment: Well, your code is working perfectly fine in VS 2015, using breakpoints and calling the inheritance chain. Everything is OK. Problem must lie elswhere.

Comment: @CodeCaster so what about questions where you cant provide a MCVE that are about principles and concepts of programming? Any other remarks on my question other than missing the reproducible code?

Comment: Your question is not about principles and concepts, it's about a concrete problem and not reproducible at the moment.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i added some more info. How would i debug about the thread issue?

Comment: What does the call-stack look like? You surely get a clue where you actually are from the call-stack.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for not helping

Comment: I'm trying to help you ask an answerable question; this one is not answerable. But thanks to that comment I'm out of here and wish you good luck. :)

Comment: @FrankM thanks for assuring that this should work in principle! Now the hard part is to debug it further.

Comment: Could you provide the code, where you instanciate the Test class and call the method?

Comment: @FrankM that is part of the framework, so `Test` is actually like a plugin of some sort which has a defined entrypoint `startup` which is called by the framework. Thanks for sticking around, what could be an issue when calling?

Comment: I was hunting for typos or such small thingies, one overlooks sometimes ,since the logical code stuff is ok, as far i can tell. basically, extending the search range. Stupid Question: have you tried turning it off and on again? ,)

Comment: @FrankM i was at that point already, not helping unfortunately